Load custom kernel image
Complete novice here.
I want to load and test a custom kernel image on my Raspberry Pi-5
Looking various tutorials , i am able to compile and get a kernel8.img that does nothing but a LED toggle.
Now, the question is how do I test this ? Can I just take a memory card, format it and just copy kernel8.img on the SD card and that's it ?

have you tried what you said?

No. i have only 1 pi and memory card, so dont want to screw up anything

do you have a USB thumb drive? Use that to test

u mean just copy the kernel8.img to a usb drive and use it to boot up instead of sd card ?
do i need to add the line -> program_usb_boot_mode=1 in /boot/cmdline.txt for this ?

Just back up the card before you do this.  If you wrote an OS kernel that just blinks an LED, even if it doesn't work it is unlikely to wreck havoc on the card.  But do make a backup.
